# What is the property or method needed to get user group information?

Tags: tridion, tridion-2011

After creating the new user object, how to get the group name of the particular user? Which property do I have to use? I have checked the `userdata` class, I didn't find any groupd details in there.

```
UserData user = (UserData)csClient.Read(usertcmid, readoption);
```

Comment: The UserData object has a GroupMemberships property, containing a list of GroupMembershipData objects, which contains a Group property (GroupData).

Comment: You are right Arjen. For some reason, I am always using TrusteeData to get that information.

Comment: @user1428019 is your question answered? If so then please mark it as answered :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Updated code with information from Arjen

```
UserData user = (UserData)csClient.Read(usertcmid, readoption);
user.GroupMemberships() // returns GroupMembershipData enumeration
```

Comment: Ram, I havent checked the code yet, will do it by morning. and one question i have in this. Groupmemberships is the property of the user data class right? is there any title or idref for groupmemberships property to take the group title or id?

Comment: GroupMemberships() provides all the group information belong to that user. It does not take the group title or id. You need to iterate through the GroupMembershipData to get the Group and Scope etc..

Comment: UserData user = client.GetCurrentUser(); 

foreach(GroupMembershipData groupMembershipData in user.GroupMemberships)
{
    Console.WriteLine(groupMembershipData.Group.Title);
}